# ufw remains disabled after a reboot using Ubuntu Server 16.04

Tags: boot, firewall, ufw

My server uses ufw to set up a simple firewall. I noticed however that the ufw firewall remained disabled after a reboot: `ufw status` reported "disabled" always.

I checked the following:

- The `/etc/ufw/ufw.conf` file contained `ENABLED=yes`.
- The service was correctly registered with `systemctl`, and looking in the `/var/log/syslog` file I could see the line "Starting Uncomplicated firewall", which proved it was at least started
- A very odd thing was that even though the firewall was saying it was disabled the system log still showed audit log lines.
- `iptables -L` showed that indeed all of the usual configuration was gone.

Answer (score 9):

The cause of this problem was that the service netfilter-persistent (also called iptables-persistent on other distributions) was enabled on the system, and this ran after ufw was disabled. This overwrote the ipfilter configuration from ufw.

I disabled netfilter-persistent:

```
$ sudo systemctl disable netfilter-persistent
```

and after that booting properly enabled ufw.