# How do I get ufw to start on boot?

Tags: firewall, systemd, ufw

UFW is not starting for me on boot. My `/etc/ufw/ufw.conf` file looks like this:

```
# /etc/ufw/ufw.conf
#

# Set to yes to start on boot. If setting this remotely, be sure to add a rule
# to allow your remote connection before starting ufw. Eg: 'ufw allow 22/tcp'
ENABLED=yes

# Please use the 'ufw' command to set the loglevel. Eg: 'ufw logging medium'.
# See 'man ufw' for details.
LOGLEVEL=low
```

So it seems it should start ok. However straight after boot I always get this:

```
$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

Using the "service" script to start it does not seem to work:

```
$ sudo service ufw start
$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

If I force a reload it will work just fine:

```
$ sudo ufw reload
Firewall reloaded
$ sudo ufw status
Status: active
```

And after that the "service" script works just fine:

```
$ sudo ufw status
Status: active
$ sudo service ufw stop
$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
$ sudo service ufw start
$ sudo ufw status
Status: active
```

How do I get ufw to start on boot?

Edit:

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 so systemd is being used. `systemctl is-enabled` reports as follows:

```
$ sudo ufw status verbose
Status: inactive
$ sudo systemctl is-enabled ufw.service
enabled
```

I also tried this:

```
$ sudo systemctl enable ufw
Synchronizing state of ufw.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable ufw
$ sudo ufw status verbose
Status: inactive
```

And after a reboot it remains inactive. `journalctl -p err` reports nothing interesting. `journalctl -u ufw` reports:

```
$ journalctl -u ufw
...<snip>...
-- Reboot --
May 26 12:53:36 matt-laptop systemd[1]: Started Uncomplicated firewall.
```

So it certainly appears that it is *attempting* to start up ufw...it just seems that it doesn't actually *do* it!

Comment: Did you try `ufw enable`? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW

Comment: Yes - thanks for the suggestion, but I've tried that. `ufw enable` successfully starts the firewall and sets `ENABLED=yes` in `ufw.conf` (it if isn't already set to "yes"). But this makes no difference. After a reboot ufw is still inactive.

Comment: Same behavior for me... I think it started when I upgraded to 22.04, or maybe 21.10, I can't remember... I am on 23.04 now with still the same problem.

Answer (score 16):

I came up with a solution of sorts. I made this edit to `/lib/systemd/system/ufw.service`:

```
$ diff -u ufw.service.orig ufw.service
--- ufw.service.orig    2018-05-26 13:45:48.696356561 +0100
+++ ufw.service 2018-05-26 13:46:04.443673265 +0100
@@ -2,7 +2,7 @@
 Description=Uncomplicated firewall
 Documentation=man:ufw(8)
 DefaultDependencies=no
-Before=network.target
+After=network.target
 
 [Service]
 Type=oneshot
```

So, this causes `ufw` to start after the network is up instead of before it. This seems to do the trick - ufw is always enabled after I boot. I don't know if this is the best way to do things. I worry that there is a small window of time between the network starting and the firewall starting... but at least it starts which is better than before!

Maybe someone can come up with a better solution. Or maybe this is the correct way to do things - in which case is it a bug that it defaults to starting before the network?

Edit:

An even better solution is:

```
$ diff -u ufw.service.orig ufw.service
--- ufw.service.orig    2018-05-26 13:45:48.696356561 +0100
+++ ufw.service 2018-05-26 14:17:22.030681670 +0100
@@ -2,7 +2,7 @@
 Description=Uncomplicated firewall
 Documentation=man:ufw(8)
 DefaultDependencies=no
-Before=network.target
+After=network-pre.target
 
 [Service]
 Type=oneshot
```

According to this page

https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget/

the `network-pre.target` has this purpose:

> Its primary purpose is for usage with firewall services that want to establish a firewall before any network interface is up.

Which really makes me wonder why it wasn't set to this by default. Setting it to this value seems to solve all my problems.

Comment: It's curios that the fix in the ufw repo is different: [first commit](https://git.launchpad.net/ufw/commit/?id=b3b831af27e7325085d91f42688620c13640f8f9), [second commit](https://git.launchpad.net/ufw/commit/?id=66457982870852f59a498039f2131764851226d3), result `Before=network-pre.target
Wants=network-pre.target local-fs.target
After=local-fs.target`

Comment: I have the same as @salmin mention under 23.04, but its still broken. I will try flipping it to; `Before=network.target
Wants=network-pre.target local-fs.target
After=network-pre.target
`

Comment: @MathieuJ. It seems to me that neither the answer above nor the change in ufw repo are relevant to the root cause. Problems I saw were caused not by ufw itself but by other services overriding the iptables after ufw. Modifying Wants/Before/After alters the order of iptables updates and can help in some cases. However the root case is that multiple services fight over iptables control and apply conflicting changes. Good solution is to uninstall/disable/reconfigure them to avoid conflicts. I'm aware of issues with {ipset,iptables,netfilter}-persistent and firewalld pkgs but there could be more

Comment: I've formatted the above comment as a full answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1480609/1639205

Answer (score 4):

> The fix is simple; we need to tell the operating system to load ufw after the netfilter-persistent

Run this command:

```
sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/ufw.service
```

And add this text:

```
[Unit]
 Description=Uncomplicated firewall
 Documentation=man:ufw(8)
 DefaultDependencies=no
 Before=network.target
 After=netfilter-persistent.service

 [Service]
 Type=oneshot
 RemainAfterExit=yes
 ExecStart=/lib/ufw/ufw-init start quiet
 ExecStop=/lib/ufw/ufw-init stop

 [Install]
 WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Source: [UFW service not loading after a reboot](https://devtidbits.com/2019/07/31/ufw-service-not-loading-after-a-reboot/)

Comment: or for the same effect but to survive systemd updates: `mkdir /etc/systemd/system/ufw.service.d` and then `echo -e "[Unit]\nAfter=netfilter-persistent.service" >/etc/systemd/system/ufw.service.d/extend.conf`

Answer (score 2):

I have a vanilla version of Debian, not Ubuntu, but this was the best post I could find to get ufw to load at startup. The suggestions here did not work for me but provided enough clues for me to eventually get it working.

In the end **I only had to change one line**. Everything else I left alone.

- Edit the UNIT section in the `ufw.service` file.
- Change `Before=network.target` to `After=network-online.target`

Saved it, rebooted and ufw was running

Note that if you disable ufw and reboot it will be disabled. If ufw is enabled and you reboot, it will be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

A common problem occurs when the ufw service is enabled and initializes successfully (i.e. updates the iptables) after the reboot, but then **the iptables get overridden by some other service later in the chain.**

If that's the case, you will see a successful ufw start in system logs and an inactive firewall afterwards.

```
$ journalctl -b -u ufw.service
-- Logs begin at Sun 2023-02-26 ...
Jul 20 10:02:56 ... systemd[1]: Finished Uncomplicated firewall.

$ ufw status
Status: inactive
```

Modifying Before/After/Wants in the service config as suggested in other answers changes the order in which services start. So it helps if the problematic services moves before the ufw.

However the root cause remains: multiple services fight over the iptables control and apply conflicting changes. A better solution is to find and uninstall/deactivate/reconfigure the problematic service. Known offenders include {ipset,iptables,netfilter}-persistent and firewalld but likely there are many more in the wild.

You can try reviewing installed packages that depend on iptables (and potentially alter it) like this:

```
$ apt-cache rdepends --installed iptables
```

Or examine services started after the ufw in systemd logs.

Other stackexchange answers on the topic:

- https://askubuntu.com/a/851166/1639205
- https://askubuntu.com/a/1475304/1639205
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/611597/386324

**If you find other packages/services that effectively disable the ufw please post them in the comments, it is greatly appreciated.**

**PS** A similar and even trickier issue of this kind is caused by docker. It doesn't visibly deactivate the ufw but creates additional rules that can expose all your containers to the external network. This problem is described at length here: https://github.com/chaifeng/ufw-docker

Answer (score 0):

Only this solution is work (add to crontab):

```
@reboot sleep 120 && /usr/sbin/ufw reload
```

Answer (score -3):

Edit the file:

```
/etc/ufw/ufw.conf
```

Set to yes to start on boot. If setting this remotely, be sure to add a rule
to allow your remote connection before starting ufw. Eg: `ufw allow 22/tcp`

```
ENABLED=yes
ufw allow 22/tcp
```

Please use the `ufw` command to set the loglevel. Eg:

```
ufw logging medium
```

See 'man ufw' for details.

```
LOGLEVEL=low
```

Comment: # /etc/ufw/ufw.conf
#

# Set to yes to start on boot. If setting this remotely, be sure to add a rule
# to allow your remote connection before starting ufw. Eg: 'ufw allow 22/tcp'
ENABLED=yes
ufw allow 22/tcp
# Please use the 'ufw' command to set the loglevel. Eg: 'ufw logging medium'.
# See 'man ufw' for details.
LOGLEVEL=low

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by “Set to yes to start on boot.”?  The OP’s `/etc/ufw/ufw.conf` file already says `ENABLED=yes`.  Should they *add* a line to request start on boot?  What, exactly, should it say?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.